# Using variables in Angular 4 animation

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I have a component with an expandable section and I'd like to dynamically set the starting height, based on the number of elements it contains.

I got the animation working with a fixed starting height `120px` and a wildcard state `*` but I'd like to be able to change the `120px` to `50px` dynamically, based on whether `list_length > 1`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'awaken-card',
  templateUrl: 'awaken-card.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        height: '120px',  // <--- set this dynamically
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        height: '*'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('300ms ease-out')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('300ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AwakenCardComponent {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() subtitle: string;
  @Input() type: string[];
  @Input() expandable: boolean = false;
  @Input() show_fade: boolean;
  @Input() items: any[];
  @Input() list_length: number;
  @Input() isExpanded: boolean;
  @Input() editable: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('expandable_section') expandable_section: ElementRef;

  constructor( private animService: AnimationProvider, private rd: Renderer2 ) {
    console.log(this)
  }

  toggleSection() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded
  }

}
```

The relevant section of the html is here:

```
<div class="card-footer" *ngIf="expandable">

  <!-- This is the animation -->
  <div class="expandable"
       *ngIf="expandable && list_length > 0"
       [@heroState]="isExpanded ? 'active' : 'inactive'"
  >
    <ion-list class="awaken bordered" no-lines>

      <ng-content select="[card-list]"></ng-content>

    </ion-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are 50px and 120px the div content's fixed height or just to adjust content's height?